# Is the speed of a single gas molecule in a box moderated (is the Maxwell Boltzmann curve narrowed)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, kinematics

I see the second law of thermodynamics
as an observed law, not an imposed law:
it is broken sometimes on a larger scale
and broken often on a molecular scale.

So, if a box contains only one gas molecule,
will that molecule experience the same range of speeds
as the many molecules of a larger sample?

I.E. Is the molecule moderated by its impacts with
the solid walls of the container?
does its Maxwell-Boltzmann curve gets narrower & higher?

If it is moderated, then consider the following.

Zeolites are porous minerals, used, for example,
to filter isobutane from butane.
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeolite)

Consider a thin horizontal slab of zeolite
bisecting a container.

The bottom half of the horizontal slab is soaked with a solvent.

Above & below the slab
is a gas that's weakly soluble in that solvent.

If, within the upper half of the slab,
the solid walls of the tiny zeolite chambers
moderate the gas
then the free gas would have fewer slow (& fewer fast) molecules
than normal.

Slow moving free gas molecules
must be more soluble
than fast moving free gas molecules.

So the free gas,
within the zeolite, facing the upper surface of the solvent,
must be less soluble
than the free gas,
outside the zeolite, facing the lower surface of the solvent.

Hence, more free gas leaves the upper surface of the solvent
than dissolves back into it.
Hence the solvent, there, becomes depleted.

Whereas the free gas facing the lower face of the solvent
would be un-moderated
and so would dissolve
into the body of depleted liquid.

Hence there would be, overall, an upward movement of gas
through the slab,
resulting in a higher pressure in the upper half of the container
than the lower half.

If that pressure difference were used (turbine taking power away) then the whole container would drop in temperature
slowing & halting the process.

But if the container were put say, in a stream,
then the process would stabilise & continue.

I’ve had this idea for decades
(it’s like Maxwell’s demon but more convincing).
I highly doubt it will work, but I don’t know why.
Can anyone tell me.

Many thanks,
David Porter.

Obviously physics is not my field.  I am a philosopher.

Comment: Considerations like these are standard for chemical processes. Nothing weird will happen; the system will find an equilibrium so that the rate of the gas coming out of the solvent is the same rate as the gas absorbed by the solvent, on both sides of the solvent, which can be different if the situation requires it. It will not be able to act as a Maxwell's demon. The zeolite wall has a temperature, and the gas molecules that bounce off that will equilibriate with that, ending up with the same kinetic energy distribution before and after collisions.

Comment: Hmm.  There's no chemical process.  Nevertheless, it won't work.  I wonder if the gas is moderated though, and if there's a potential idea there?

Comment: Is the Maxwell Boltzmann curve for the zeolite, though very much lower than for the gas, also a narrower curve;  narrower because it's a solid, bound: less kinetic energy, more electrical(?) energy?

Comment: I suppose the answer may be "Yes, but it would make no difference".  Ah well.  All hopes on nuclear fusion.

Comment: I am trying to tell you that these physical considerations are necessary to get chemical reactions correct, even if there is no chemical process in your particular situation. No, the zeolite would have to be modelled by a different distribution, related to the Maxwell-Boltzmann. It does not matter, because thermal equilibrium requires that the different distributions be mathematically compatible with each other.

Comment: Many thanks (including for your patience).  I get it, there would be thermal consistency throughout the whole process, or rather non-process.

Comment: you wrote: "it is broken sometimes on a larger scale", what specifically you have in mind here?

Comment: My, relatively layman's, understanding of the second law of thermodynamics is that it's often broken regarding a group of, say, 5 or 10, molecules, so I assume it's broken also by a group of, say, a thousand molecules, though extremely rarely.  I just wanted to illustrate that it is an observed law, not an imposed law, giving hope to the prospect of making a device designed to break it on an even larger scale.  Otherwise no-one will even try.